# User Location Will Not display on mapView

Tags: ios, iphone

I am creating a simple UIMapView with custom annotations. Just upgraded to Yosemite and Xcode 6.1.1. I have tried everything to get user location to show on map but for some reason the blue dot doesn't show on the map. I have selected show user location in the inspector for the UIMapView. The error listed at the end shows in the log window at the bottom of the screen when I run it on my phone.  Thank you for any help.

My .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h> 
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h> 


@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
```

My .m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.mapView.delegate self];
    [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
}

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = [userLocation coordinate];
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(loc, 500, 500);
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

}
```

ERROR RECEIVED AFTER RUNNING
501:107687] Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.

Comment: So.. that error message is pretty clear to me. You need to ask for authorization...

Comment: Quick Google search reveals *DOZENS* of examples https://www.google.com/search?q=CLLocationManager+requestWhenInUseAuthorization&oq=CLLocationManager+requestWhenInUseAuthorization&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.404j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Particularly, you should call this *BEFORE* your call to setShowsUserLocation in the ViewDidLoad... so wrap your authentication in a BOOL method and only call the map methods then...

Comment: if([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
            [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

Comment: @zaheer yep, that's a totally valid way of doing it too...

Answer (score 0):

As per my comments on the question... you are in a Permission error situation. 
You need t check for User Permission before you call the update methods...

```
CLAuthorizationStatus authorizationStatus= [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

if (authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized ||
    authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways ||
    authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {

    // update location here...      

}
```

Then, as pointed out by @zaheer, you need to add a Key-Value par to the -Info.plist

NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
Some Message To The User About Why You Want Their Location

or

NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription 
Some Witty Comment About The NSA

depending upon whether you need the location only when the app is in the foreground, or in the background...

Comment: Also have to add, NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription, NSLocationAlwayseUsageDescription in info.plist.